# Python: How to print specific columns with cut some strings on one of the column reading csv

Tags: python-2.7

Am new to Python, hence apologize for basic question.

I've a csv file in the below mentioned format.

```
##cat temp.csv
Id,Info,TimeStamp,Version,Numitems,speed,Path
18699504331,NA/NA/NA,2017:01:01:13:40:31,3.16,6,781.2kHz,/home/user1
31287345804,NA/NA/NA,2017:01:03:14:35:04,3.16,2,111.5MHz,/home/user2
16360534162,NA/NA/NA,2017:01:02:21:39:51,3.16,3,230MHz,/home/user3
```

I wanted to read csv and print only specific column of interest and cut some strings in one of the column in a readable fashion, so i can use it.

Here is the python code:

### cat temp.py

```
import csv                   

with open('temp.csv') as cvsfile:
readcsv = csv.reader(cvsfile, delimiter=',')
   Id =[]                                      
   Info =[]                                    
   Timestamp =[]                               
   Version =[]
   Numitems =[]
   Speed =[]
   Path =[]
   
for row in readcsv:
   lsfid = row[0]
   modelinfo = row[1]
   timestamp = row[2]
   compilever = row[3]
   numofavb = row[4]
   frequency = row[5]
   designpath = row[6]
       
   Id.append(lsfid)
   Info.append(modelinfo)
   Timestamp.append(timestamp)
   Version.append(compilever)
   Numitems.append(numofavb)
   Speed.append(frequency)
   Path.append(designpath)

   print(Id)
   print(Info)
   print(Timestamp)
   print(Version)
   print(Numitems)
   print(Speed)
   print(Path)
```

Output:

```
python temp.py
['Id', '18699504331', '31287345804', '16360534162', '18772620814', '18699504331', '31287345804', '16360534162']
['Info', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA', 'NA/NA/NA']
['TimeStamp', '2017:01:01:13:40:31', '2017:01:03:14:35:04', '2017:01:02:21:39:51', '2017:01:03:14:40:47', '2017:01:01:13:40:31', '2017:01:03:14:35:04', '2017:01:02:21:39:51']
['Version', '3.16', '3.16', '3.16', '3.16', '3.16', '3.16', '3.16']
['Numitems', '6', '2', '3', '2', '6', '2', '3']
['speed', '781.2kHz', '111.5MHz', '230MHz', '100MHz', '781.2kHz', '111.5MHz', '230MHz']
['Path', '/home/user1', '/home/user2', '/home/user3', '/home/user4', '/home/user5', '/home/user6', '/home/user7']
```

But what i wanted is in well organized look with my choice of column to be printed, something like below...

```
Id      Info        TimeStamp       Version     Numitems    speed       Path

18699504331 NA/NA/NA    2017:01:01:13:40:31 3.16        6       781.2kHz    user1
31287345804 NA/NA/NA    2017:01:02:21:39:51 3.16        2       111.5MHz    user2
31287345804 NA/NA/NA    2017:01:02:21:39:51 3.16        2       111.5MHz    user3
```

Any help could be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in Advance
Velu.V

Answer (score 0):

Check out numpy's `genfromtxt` function. You can use the use the `usecols` keyword argument to specify that you only want to read certain columns, see also https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html . For example lets say we have the following csv sheet:

```
col1 , col2 , col3
0.5, test, 0.3 
0.7, test2, 0.1
```

Then,

```
import numpy as np
table=np.genfromtxt(f,delimiter=',',skip_header=0,dtype='S',usecols=[0,1])
```

will load the first two columns. You can then use the tabulate package ( https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) to nicely print out your table.

```
print tabulate(table,headers='firstrow')
```

Will look like:

```
  col1    col2
-------  --------
    0.5  test
    0.7  test2
```

Hope that answers your question